# Command pattern implementation or adaption

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern

I have different commands that all share some common data, so I extracted that to a super-class `Command`. All the concrete commands operate on an object of `Foo` when they implement the `execute` method. The actual invoker of the command is a client `TheClient` that creates a new object of the required command and directly executes it.

I have implemented it in such a way that the client and inovker is independent from the implementation details in the commands, and more importantly, independent from the class `Foo`.

I have the following questions:

1) Is this an implementation of the command pattern, or somehow an adoption of it?

2) From my understanding of the command pattern, in this example `Foo` is the receiver. Is this correct?

3) In contrast to the pure command pattern, I have merged the invoker and client into the same class. Some people say that this is OK in the command pattern, since both are a theoretical construct and in an actual implementation they can be in the same class. Is this correct?

```
public abstract class Command {
  protected String a;
  protected Foo foo;
  public Command(String a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.foo = new Foo(a);
  }
  public abstract void execute();
}

public class StartCommand extends Command {
  private String b;
  public StartCommand(String a, String b) {
    super(a);
    this.b = b;
  }
  public void execute() {
    this.foo.doSomething("start " + a + " with " + b);
  }
}

// ... other commands ...

public class Foo {
  protected String name;
  public Foo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void doSomething(String action) {
    // does something...
  }
}

public class TheClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Command command = new StartCommand("x", "y");
    command.execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1st question: Yes. It is an adaptation of the Command pattern.

2nd question: `Foo` is the receiver.

3rd question: Yes, the invoker is merged with the client class. Here comes a little problem. The `Foo` is not independent from the concrete `StartCommand`. It's true, that You have to modify the `Command` class both implementation, when a rename occurs on the `Foo` class for example, but the instantiation of the `Foo` should be somewhere in the `main` if You ask Uncle Bob. In Your example it's in the `Command`'s constructor.

**EDIT**

You can instantiate `Foo` in somewhere else, than wrap it around with the ConcreteCommand. Than [Invoker](http://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/invoker) will [latch](http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/34100000/Facehugger-aliens-vs-predator-34192985-400-504.jpg) around the command. Both wrapping around will embrace Decoupling, and Single Responsibility.

For example You can test `Foo`'s every behaviour without being afraid of any side effect of the Command. In the test You create a `Foo`, test it around, no surprise. Testing the `StartCommand` You have to check if any method chaining happens. Like this:

```
public Command.SetAOfFoo(string a) {
    this.foo.SetA(a);
}
```

You have to check all `Foo`'s properties to hold, that You checked in the first time with the unit tests of `Foo`. You will find some failing testcases because some calling to the `StartCommand` modified the state of `Foo`, and that lead to failing tests.

I know that is far away from the code that You provided, but `this.foo = new Foo(a);` is close to the imaginary `this.foo.SetA(a)` that I wrote as an example.

In Your example, there was a possible programming problem. Both the constructor of `Foo` and the `StartCommand`'s constructor got the value `'a'` as parameter. What if You make it public? And You are very surprised, by setting the `'a'` in the `StartCommand`, the printout changes, but `Foo` behaves differently. The constructor of `Foo` stored the previous value, and You maybe forget to change of the code of the Command, to pass the new value to `Foo`, where You forget to make the `'a'` public.

The whole example's headscratching can be avoided with removing the construction of `Foo` from `Command`.

Comment: For some reason I cannot instantiate ``Foo`` in the client, so I cannot use the _pure_ command pattern, correct?

Comment: @user3510462 I have edited the post. Why can't You instantiate `Foo` in the client? Can You instantiate anywhere else, than the `Command`?

Comment: ``Foo`` is from a third-party library and I don't want any dependencies to it in my client project.

Comment: So the `TheClient` is in different project, than the `Command` class, and You include the library only in the latter project?

Answer (score 0):

1)it seems to be adaption to command pattern.

2)`Foo` is receiver so it knows how to carry out request.`doSomething()`

3).They can be in same class but it violates some design principles like single resposibility.Purpose of client in command pattern is creating objects and injecting receivers.The role of invoker is to hold commands in some data structure and calling their execute method.Simply it schedules commands and you can do a lot of thing like logging,command history and so on.And putting this kind of logic into client is too much burden for client.